# Timeout in Azure service bus (while closing MessageSender)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We are getting frequent Timeouts while calling messageSender.close().

The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:10. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:urn:uuid:8b8aa582-88b9-4ffe-b219-b831f1faf3d0, Timestamp:10/5/2016 9:01:22 PM

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [4]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.EndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.ParallelAsyncResult`1.OnCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)

Exception rethrown at [5]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [6]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SendAvailabilityPairedNamespaceMessageSender.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.EndClose(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Any chance you could share the code? Are you by any chance closing the factory that used to create the receiver before closing the receiver first? Or perhaps do something on multiple threads?

Comment: I will add the code. To answer your second question, no we do not close the factory before closing the receiver. In fact, we keep the Factory open throughout the lifetime of the application.